# Using EJB Timer Service

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a small bit of code that I'm trying to execute with the timer service.

I'm having trouble finding a good example or tutorial online. Oracle's tutorial covered a bit too much too quickly for me to grasp the basic utility that I need. I just want it to execute immediately when the program starts and then every hour after that.

What would a sample timer look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's the simplest to achieve with a [`@Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) and an additional [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) to invoke the method directly after construction:

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class SomeBackgroundJob {

    @PostConstruct
    @Schedule(hour="*/1", minute="0", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

The only difference is that it doesn't run every hour after startup, but only on every whole hour after startup. That shouldn't really matter, I think?

Comment: Thank you. No, it doesn't matter it just has to be periodic--and really I just wanted to see how it was done. Although I have tried the @ singleton with a @ PostConstruct on this EJB and it was not getting executed. I don't think the @ postConstruct was ever being invoked, for some reason. Hopefully the @ schedule fixes that.

Comment: With alone a `@Singleton` and `@PostConstruct` it would only be invoked if you inject it elsewhere. You'd need to add a `@Startup` as well to get it to invoke on startup. But that isn't necessary if you already have a `@Schedule`.

Comment: Yes that is the big problem is that I am definitely NOT invoking it anywhere at all. Thus, the reason for me trying a timer service to achieve invocation. The EJB does call another Database management EJB, however--if I could get this EJB invoked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your timer to run every hour, containerise the hour using day of the week. Here is an example

```
@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "*", hour = "*/1", persistent = false)
public void run() {
    // Do your job here.
}
```