# How to run a background job method at fixed intervals?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, background-process

I am using JSP/Servlet on Apache Tomcat. I have to run a method every 10 minutes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

As you're on Tomcat, which is just a barebones servletcontainer, you can't use EJB's `@Schedule` for this which is recommended by Java EE specification. Your best bet is then the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) from Java 1.5's `java.util.concurrent` package. You can trigger this with help of a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) like follows:

```
@WebListener
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeTask(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

where the `SomeTask` class look like this:

```
public class SomeTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

If you were actually using a real Java EE container with EJB support and all on em (like Glassfish, JBoss AS, TomEE, etc), then you could use a [`@Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) EJB with a [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) method. This way the container will worry itself about pooling and destroying threads. All you need is then the following EJB:

```
@Singleton
public class SomeTask {

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*/10", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

Note that this way you can continue transparently using container managed transactions the usual way (`@PersistenceContext` and so on), which isn't possible with `ScheduledExecutorService` — you'd have to manually obtain the entity manager and manually start/commit/end transaction, but you would by default already not have another option on a barebones servletcontainer like Tomcat anyway.

Note that you should never use a `Timer` in a supposedly "lifetime long" running Java EE web application. It has the following major problems which makes it unsuitable for use in Java EE (quoted from [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)):

- `Timer` is sensitive to changes in the system clock, `ScheduledExecutorService` isn't.
- `Timer` has only one execution thread, so long-running task can delay other tasks. `ScheduledExecutorService` can be configured with any number of threads.
- Any runtime exceptions thrown in a `TimerTask` kill that one thread, thus making `Timer` dead, i.e. scheduled tasks will not run anymore (until you restart the server). `ScheduledThreadExecutor` not only catches runtime exceptions, but it lets you handle them if you want. Task which threw exception will be canceled, but other tasks will continue to run.

Comment: Great answer, thank you @BalusC. One question though: how would i modifie the scheduler if i require to change the intervall between calls?
e.g. i have some ´int frequency´ which can be set by the user in webgui which represents the time inbetween runs in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Read on [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) it has to be initiated by a [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)

```
public class MyContext implements ServletContextListener 
{
    private ScheduledExecutorService sched;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) 
    {
        sched = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        sched.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) 
    {
        sched.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Also, you may try using the Java [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) from a [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) but it's not recommended in a Java EE container since it takes away control of the Thread resources from the container. (the first option with ScheduledExecutorService is the way to go).

```
Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");
MyTask t = new MyTask();

//Second Parameter is the specified the Starting Time for your timer in
//MilliSeconds or Date

//Third Parameter is the specified the Period between consecutive
//calling for the method.

timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000*60*10);
```

And `MyTask` that implements `TimerTask` is a class that implements the `Runnable` interface so you have to override the run method with your code:

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask 
{
  public void run() 
  { 
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I got I got it.but from where I have to call this method. I have to start this as soon  my application is up

Comment: [Never use `Timer` in Java EE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173132/stop-scheduled-timer-when-shutdown-tomcat/9186070#9186070).

Comment: Thanks @BalusC I have explicitly mentioned that in my answer.