# Failed to stop the Elasticsearch thread in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, elasticsearch

I am using Tomcat 8.x for a Spring MVC-based website. The website calls Elasticsearch in the following way:

```
private static Client client;
```

Here is how I create the client object only once:

```
public static Client getClient() {
    if (client == null) {           
        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "my_cluster")
                .build();
                
        try {
            TransportAddress[] transportAddress = new TransportAddress[1];
            for (int k=0; k<adds.length; k++) {
                transportAddress[0] = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName('127.0.0.1'), 9300);
            }
            client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings)
                    .addPlugin(DeleteByQueryPlugin.class)
                    .build()
                    .addTransportAddresses(transportAddress);
        
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to get ES client");;
        }           
    }       
    
    return client;
}
```

Here is how I use the client to access Elasticsearch:

```
public SearchResponse searchForMyPage(Long owerId, HttpServletRequest request, Account visitor, CampaignResultType type) {

    String query = 'this is my query string';
    
    if (client == null) {
        client = getClient();
    }
    
    SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch('MyIndex')
            .setTypes('MyDoc'))
            .setQuery(query)
            .setHighlighterNumOfFragments(1)
            .setSize(10).execute().actionGet();         
    return sr;
}
```

But I see many Elasticsearch related exceptions in Tomcat log. Something like the following:

```
19-May-2016 00:52:13.483 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Volpan][transport_client_worker][T#9]{New I/O worker #9}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

What is the correct way of using Elasticsearch in a Java web app?

### Update

The following is the logs of Tomcat, show many Elasticsearch related errors, from the moment of Tomcat start to its shutdown.

```
20-May-2016 21:43:11.219 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][[timer]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$EstimatedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:703)
20-May-2016 21:43:11.219 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][scheduler][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20-May-2016 21:43:11.220 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20-May-2016 21:43:11.221 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][transport_client_worker][T#2]{New I/O worker #2}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20-May-2016 21:43:11.221 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][transport_client_worker][T#3]{New I/O worker #3}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20-May-2016 21:43:11.222 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][transport_client_worker][T#4]{New I/O worker #4}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:296)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:278)
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:159)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:68)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.select(AbstractNioSelector.java:434)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:212)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20-May-2016 21:43:11.223 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[War Machine][transport_client_worker][T#5]{New I/O worker #5}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `client.close()` when your application shuts down. How you do that depends on the specifics of your java web app.

For example (code copied from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173132/stop-scheduled-timer-when-shutdown-tomcat/9186070#9186070)), applicable for [Servlet 3.0 spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315):

```
@WebListener
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new YourParsingJob(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.HOUR);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Or with Spring, in the class you create the client, define a `@PreDestroy` annotated method and call `client.close()` there:

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
  client.close();
}
```

Comment: Andrei, thanks for helping me! By "when your application shuts down", you mean shutting it down when a thread/web request is over? I hear that obtaining client is an expensive operation and so I made it static for reuse.    Does `client.close` mean each time a new client has to be recreated? As you know, this is a web application.

Comment: No, I mean when you shutdown Tomcat, because those messages refer to starting/stopping Tomcat.

Comment: Andrei, I saw tons of these messages, not at the moment of Tomcat shutdown or start. It seems such message is thrown for each call to Elasticsearch. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, are you sure your code is using the same Client instance? Doesn't sound like it does....

Comment: Andrei, you are right. The errors I have seems out of one failed stop and the program continues spew out error messages.

Comment: Andrei, I updated with a segment of the log file. It appears the issue was caused by ONE failed stop of Elasticsearch thread, which generates error messages continuously. If I use your `public void destroy() {}` approach, what is the point of me having a static client object for reuse? Thanks!