# Tomcat shutdown : Failed to stop Timer-0

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, timer, derby

I get the following exception in Tomcat shutdown :

```
 thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I am using embedded Derby in my server which uses

> org.apache.derby.iapi.services.timer.TimerFactory

which constructs a `TimerThread` in

> java.util.Timer

which causes the issue ([Stop scheduled timer when shutdown tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173132/stop-scheduled-timer-when-shutdown-tomcat)) .

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Perhaps you are not shutting down Derby before you shutdown Tomcat? https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/devguide/tdevdvlp20349.html