# Creating Scheduler on postconstruct method on application scoped bean

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, cdi, java-ee-7

Is it valid to created the Scheduler the job on PostConstruct method of the ApplicationScoped bean.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class myBean {

    private String name = "Soup of the day";

    @Schedule(hour="0", persistent=false)
    @PostConstruct
    public void afterCreate() {
        System.out.println("Bean Created");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve by this?

Comment: You will get the function called both on construction and by timer.

Comment: @AlexNevidomsky. Thanks for replying. I have soem database calls. I am trying to run them on application startup and also every night. So thought of this approach. Can you help me

Comment: I don't see then, why can't you have afterCreate() and onTimer() functions both calling databaseCall() that would do the job (instead of placing two annotations on afterCreate() )?

Comment: Here's an example of doing it your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482764/using-ejb-timer-service

Answer (score 0):

A `@Singleton` EJB with `@Startup` annotation (on class) and `@Schedule` annotation (on the method) should suffice. You do not need to use `@PostConstruct` since that would force you to inject the Singleton EJB instance some where (which I am assuming is not possible given your use case)